# maven 3 javadoc plugin ignores configuration

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-3, maven-site-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I use maven 3 and have my javadoc configured according to the new maven 3 siteplugin+javadoc configuration. However all of my javadoc configuration parameters seem to be ignored. So no package grouping, no source linking etc.

My project is a multi module project, the command I use is: mvn3 clean package javadoc:aggregate

Here is the relevent part of my root pom.:

```
<build>
    <!-- Memory management properties for jenkins build. -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmn8m -Xms32m -Xmx96m -XX:PermSize=32m
                        -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0-beta-3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <groups>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Hypercube</title>
                                        <packages>org.hypercube*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Hyperdrive</title>
                                        <packages>org.hyperdrive*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Hydrogen</title>
                                        <packages>org.hydrogen*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Fusion-X11</title>
                                        <packages>org.fusion.x11*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Fusion-Qt</title>
                                        <packages>org.fusion.qt*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                </groups>
                                <linksource>true</linksource>
                                <minmemory>16m</minmemory>
                                <maxmemory>128m</maxmemory>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because Maven separates between the plugin-config of plugins and reportplugins inside the configuration of the site-plugin. The snippet you post will only take action when running `mvn site`, not the javadoc goals directly. This behavior effects all plugins. Afaik is the only way to duplicate the configuration to a "normal" plugin-config like this:

```
<build>
    <!-- Memory management properties for jenkins build. -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmn8m -Xms32m -Xmx96m -XX:PermSize=32m
                        -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0-beta-3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <groups>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Hypercube</title>
                                        <packages>org.hypercube*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Hyperdrive</title>
                                        <packages>org.hyperdrive*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Hydrogen</title>
                                        <packages>org.hydrogen*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Fusion-X11</title>
                                        <packages>org.fusion.x11*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <title>Fusion-Qt</title>
                                        <packages>org.fusion.qt*</packages>
                                    </group>
                                </groups>
                                <linksource>true</linksource>
                                <minmemory>16m</minmemory>
                                <maxmemory>128m</maxmemory>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8</version>
              <configuration>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
              <groups>
                <group>
                    <title>Hypercube</title>
                    <packages>org.hypercube*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <title>Hyperdrive</title>
                    <packages>org.hyperdrive*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <title>Hydrogen</title>
                    <packages>org.hydrogen*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <title>Fusion-X11</title>
                    <packages>org.fusion.x11*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <title>Fusion-Qt</title>
                    <packages>org.fusion.qt*</packages>
                </group>
              </groups>
              <linksource>true</linksource>
              <minmemory>16m</minmemory>
              <maxmemory>128m</maxmemory>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Just do not expect this "design" to be fixed soon, there are numerous bugs reported and the speed of changes is not exactly fast.

Comment: On a JMPS/Jigsaw modularized project, I am trying to run javadoc:aggregate and the javadoc plugin configuration is being ignored. I have tried a bunch of solutions and nothing seems to work.